# ByteCode Instructions: Do I understand well

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

I am learning about Java Bytecodes.
I would like to know if I am understand correctly this bytecode process

I did not finished, but It is just to begin on the good way..

```
00000000    aload_0 
// load param1 (String)
// Stack is [StringParam]
00000001    invokevirtual       char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray() 
// split variable in an array of char
// Stack is [ReferenceToCharArray] ?
00000004    dup 
// duplicate the top of operand stack and put it back at the end
// Stack is now [ReferenceToCharArray ReferenceToCharArray]
00000005    arraylength 
// Return array's length
// Stack is now [ReferenceToCharArray ArrayLength]
00000006    iconst_2 
// push 2 in stack
// Stack is now [ReferenceToCharArray ArrayLength 2]
00000007    if_icmpge           pos.00000013
// If the Array length is greater or equals to 2
// Stack is now [ReferenceToCharArray]
00000013    areturn
// Return the array
// Stack is empty
```

Comment: btw, why close votes, it's a valid question?

Comment: just a small question, do you understand what's the return type of the function from the code?

Comment: This is a part of a function I am looking. I think the return type is an array of char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stack is wrong after the invoke virtual, param1 is no longer top of stack.  And I don't think 3 ever gets put on the stack.

What the if_icmpge is really doing is comparing the length of the char array returned by the invokevirtual to 2

Comment: this is the correct answer, I was about to say it compares the length of the array to 2, but it's done already :)

Comment: I updated my initial answer. Can someone can validate my new stack ?